Do 'avoid' notes depend on register?
Looking at 'avoid' notes, it seems that the general rule is: do not play a note which is a minor second above a chord note e.g avoid F over a C major chord as this forms a minor 2nd interval with E.
This is understandable. However, if I play F, but this time the chord note E is above it in pitch, I am no longer playing a minor 9th from a chord note (E-F), but a non chord note forming a major 7th interval with a chord note (F-E). In this context, is the F still seen as an 'avoid' note, even though it is no longer forming the minor 9th interval?

Some chords have members that are a minor second above another member; how do you square that with this rule?

Like French Augmented Sixths? (Yes, I do, but only in certain positions....)

@phoog "Avoid tone" comes from the chord/scale system where chord=scale, scale=chord. G7 = G mixolydian scale where Ab would be an "avoid tone". If you want a G7b9 chord the system then says that is equal to some scale, most likely the fifth mode of harmonic minor. The system makes no attempt to recognize what tonality the chord occurs in.

@MichaelCurtis so the avoidance is in the context of a solo over the given tone, i.e., a non-chord tone that should be avoided?

@phoog, yes, that's right.

The "avoid tone" idea does not give consideration to duration, metrical placement, or any other pitches used in a melodic line, which unfortunately forces us to discuss the concept in a contextless, artificial way.

"Avoid tone" descriptions do not normally consider octave and imply all tones in a close position, like example (a). Your description of a voicing with E F in a minor ninth relationship implies example (b) where the close voicing of the C major triad reinforces the sense that C is the chord and F5 is the dissonant "avoid tone." If you position the E and F into a major seventh relationship, you have potential voicings like examples (c) and (d), and in this artificial context the relationship of the three lower voices could be described as a Cusu4 chord, and that would render the E as the "avoid tone."
My point about examples (c) and (d) is really just another way of describing the "avoid tone" idea. Even if you arrange the chord voicing to lessen harshness of the E against F dissonance, if you over-emphasize the F, you sort of transform the C of the lead sheet into a Csus4. Maybe that is a problem. Maybe it isn't. Either way the potential confusion about which tones are consonant and which are dissonant is what the "avoid tone" idea is hoping to avoid. It just avoids the problem rather than teaching how to handle dissonance with taste.

So-called "avoid" notes are not that general. It's true that scale degree 4 over a major I chord (e.g., F played against C major) is prone to sounding bad, but it's not solely because of the minor second relationship against the E. For example, b6 against a major chord — a minor second above the chordal fifth — can create a very pleasing tension.
It's also true that dissonances can be ameliorated by moving them further apart and by adding intervening tones. But if one ascribes to the idea of avoid notes, then those guidelines are generally treated fairly strictly — one would avoid F against C major regardless the voicing of the chord and the relative placement of the F.

The 'rules' of harmony are not particularly applicable in jazz situations - to an extent, that's what makes jazz jazz! In any case, those 'rules' are more along the banner 'guidelines', and often don't get adhered to like 'rules' ought to.
As a simple example, I often play a Dm chord with an E note next to the D and the F, which, according to the 'rules', is verboden.
So, the best check with all these things is - try it, and if you like the sound, particularly playing jazz, keep playing it.
It's often the case with extended chords to play an 'avoid' note an octave higher, as yes, it will sound more acceptable to more folk, but that's hardly a reason to eschew the idea. Go with your ears!

But concept of avoid notes does come from jazz theory.

@Lazy - I don't and never have denied that!

Yes, but your first paragraph makes it sound as if this was a concept from regular harmony theory that cannot be applied directly to jazz. Although it is less even a harmonic rule, but rather a heuristic. When my composition teacher taught us you can put any note in a major chord except for the natural fourth I composed a piece that heavily relied on doing so, just out of spite!

In a Dm chord, E isn't a semitone above a chord note, so it isn't an 'avoid'.

Sort of.  The higher an 'outside' note comes in the voicing, the easier it is to accept it as a chord extension rather than a clunker.
